# Next button only brings the first image and stops

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to create a next and back buttons that go through the images one by one that are in the table.

But the next button, it only brings the first image and stops.

How can the same button "next" have the function of going through all the images?

```
<p id = "slider"></p>
<div id="galDiv">
<style>
table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;}
</style>
<table>
<tr>
<td id="1"><img src="gallery/a.jpg" style="width:100px;height:100px;"></td>
<td id="2"><img src="gallery/k.jpg" style="width:100px;height:100px;"></td>
<td id="3"><img src="gallery/2.jpg" style="width:100px;height:100px;" ></td>
<td id="4"><img src="gallery/3.jpg" style="width:100px;height:100px;" ></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<button id="nxt">NEXT</button>

 <script>
 document.getElementById("nxt").onclick = function() 
 {myFunction()};
 function myFunction() { 
 var div = document.getElementById('galDiv');
 var nextSibling = div.nextSibling; 
 while(nextSibling && nextSibling.nodeType != 1) {
 nextSibling = nextSibling.nextSibling }
  } 
  </script>
```

How can also create a back button ?

Comment: Have you thought about making the other cells non-visible? This way, you just change the CSS of the cell you want to present. Back & Next buttons just tell the script which cell to show/hide.

Comment: no didnt think of that but would it work for all the images, because i have tried a few different ways and nothing is really working

Comment: format your javascript better, walk through it step by step, and you might be able to figure it out pretty easily

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a facebook like image viewer, you shouldn't use table element.
In order to create such thing you should create a div with container fixed side ,within this div you should have a div with floating images and then your button should change the right position of the inner div.

Or you could use a jquery library such as http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox

Comment: I cant use jquery have to use javascript. Is there any online example you know of ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code does nothing. The next sibling to `#galDiv` is the `<button>`.

Is this what you wanted?

```js
 document.getElementById("nxt").onclick = myFunction;
 function myFunction() {
   var picture = [
     "firstPicture",
     "secondPicture",
     "thirdPicture",
     "fourthPicture"
   ];
   var place = {
     "firstPicture": 0,
     "secondPicture": 1,
     "thirdPicture": 2,
     "fourthPicture": 3
   };
   var table = document.querySelector('table');
   
   if (!table.className) {
     table.className = "firstPicture";
   }
   var nextPicture = (place[table.className] + 1) % 4;
   table.className = picture[nextPicture];
   
 }
```

```css
img[src="gallery/a.jpg"] {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
img[src="gallery/k.jpg"] {
  border: 5px solid green;
}
img[src="gallery/2.jpg"] {
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
img[src="gallery/3.jpg"] {
  border: 5px solid black;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  position: absolute;
  padding: none;
  border: none;
}

#galDiv {
  width: 113px;
  height: 113px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.firstPicture {
  left: 0;
}
.secondPicture {
  left: -112px;
}
.thirdPicture {
  left: -224px;
}
.fourthPicture {
  left: -336px;
}
```

```html
<p id = "slider"></p>
<div id="galDiv">
<table>
<tr>
<td id="1"><img src="gallery/a.jpg" style="width:100px;height:100px;"></td>
<td id="2"><img src="gallery/k.jpg" style="width:100px;height:100px;"></td>
<td id="3"><img src="gallery/2.jpg" style="width:100px;height:100px;" ></td>
<td id="4"><img src="gallery/3.jpg" style="width:100px;height:100px;" ></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<button id="nxt">NEXT</button>
```

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly just had change image sizes :)

Answer (score 0):

I added the curimg attribute to the slider. Read the script for yourself. You'll need to add in modulus arithmetic to round around the table entries. As for the 'prev' function. Figure out the same thing with a -1 when selecting the tdnode.

Don't forget to set the curimg attribute after you append the child.

Good luck!

```
<p id = "slider" curimg='1'></p>
<div id="galDiv">
<style>
table, th, td {

border: 1px solid black;}
</style>
<table>
<tr>
<td id="1"><img src="gallery/a.jpg" style="width:100px;height:100px;"></td>
<td id="2"><img src="gallery/k.jpg" style="width:100px;height:100px;"></td>
<td id="3"><img src="gallery/2.jpg" style="width:100px;height:100px;" ></td>
<td id="4"><img src="gallery/3.jpg" style="width:100px;height:100px;" ></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<button id="nxt">NEXT</button>

 <script>
 document.getElementById("nxt").onclick = function() 
 {myFunction()};
 function myFunction() {
 //Get the slider, parse the int of the 'curimg' attribute
 cid = document.getElementById('slider');
 current_image = parseInt( cid.getAttribute('curimg') );
 //Get the td of that id+1
 tdnode = document.getElementById(current_image + 1);
 //Clone the image childNode into the slider.
 cid.appendChild( td.childNodes[0].cloneNode() );
  } 
  </script>
```